# I'm trying to filter a list by using list.map and than put the result in a new list in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to filter a list by using list.map and than put the result in a new list in flutter ,
the problem is when i try to print the filtered list every thing is ok but in my app it's just display the first item wrong but the rest is right it always display the first item in the unfiltered list no mater what, why is that?

here is my code

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:megacosm_game_store/data/games_data.dart';
import 'package:megacosm_game_store/models/game_model.dart';
import 'package:megacosm_game_store/providers/filter_provider.dart';
import 'package:megacosm_game_store/utils/blackray_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:megacosm_game_store/utils/user_option_drawer.dart';
import 'package:megacosm_game_store/widgets/game_card.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DiscoverPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DiscoverPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DiscoverPage> createState() => _DiscoverPageState();
}

class _DiscoverPageState extends State<DiscoverPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Game> filteredGames = context.watch<FilterProvider>().filteredGames;
    var searchController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: UserOptionsDrawer(),
      appBar: BlackRayAppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 16, 16, 1),
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            height: 60,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 16, 16, 1),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 250,
                    height: 40,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: searchController,
                      cursorColor: Colors.white,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          suffixIcon: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  //Provider.of<FilterProvider>(context)
                                  //.searchGames(searchController.text);
                                  context.read<FilterProvider>().searchGames(searchController.text);
                                  /*print(games.where((element) {
                                    return element.name
                                        .toUpperCase().contains(searchController.text.toUpperCase());
                                  }).toList().first.name);
                                  print(filteredGames.first.name);
                                  filteredGames = games.where((element) {
                                    return element.name
                                        .toUpperCase().contains(searchController.text.toUpperCase());
                                  }).toList();
                                  print(filteredGames.first.name);*/
                                  
                                });
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.search_sharp,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          focusColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                          filled: true,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            borderSide:
                                BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.white24),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                        });
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.filter_alt_sharp,
                        size: 30,
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filteredGames.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GameCard(game: filteredGames[index]);
              },
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to display the filtered games correctly.

Comment: Try removing the setState in suffix in textfield as you are already watching the filtered list cubit.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider instantiating your `searchController` outside the `build` method, because each time the `build` method is called, it will create a new `searchController`. It is an unnecessary operation.

Can you please share this `context.read<FilterProvider>().searchGames(searchController.text)` function? To me, the issue seems to be because of some object reference. It will be more clear with the definition of the function.